# instantiating objects C++

Tags: c++, class

I have seen people instantiate objects in 2 different ways, which way is best and why? or is there even a difference?

```
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity(const std::string& name) : mName(name);

    ~Entity();

private:
    std::string mName;
};

int main()
{
    Entity ent("myname");
    Entity ent1 = Entity("yourname");
}
```

Comment: The first one instantiates an object on the stack, the second one (with new, which you have forgotten) instantiates an object on the heap. Stack space is quite limited, heap space is (virtually) not.

Comment: I am not using new @oliver.

Comment: The second version constructs a temporary object, then uses the copy constructor.

Comment: @melpomene copy elision says that no copy/move constructor is called.

Comment: @all: sorry, I thought it was a typo because who would use the copy ctor for first initialization? Of course the compiler will optimize it away, but it's just ugly.

Comment: There's also the possible drawback of Entity not being copy constructible nor move constructible, but that's quite rare.

Comment: @oliver: _"who would use the copy ctor for first initialization"_ Many, many people on this site. I for one am glad to see someone asking _why_.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: no problem, to each their own. I didn't mean to be mean, it's just a kind of redundancy I personally don't like.

Comment: @oliver: About the code you are absolutely right - it's silly and nobody should write code like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Entity ent("myname");
```

This allocates space on the stack for the Entity and then calls the constructor to initialize the class in place with myname.

```
Entity ent1 = Entity("yourname");
```

This (unoptimized) creates two Entity. The second calls the constructor to initialize the class with "yourname" and then uses the copy constructor to initialize ent1. The annonymous Entity is then destructed. There are some complex rules about how or when extra copies can be eliminated but keeping them all straight makes my head spin.

So the first form is preferable because it requires no thought about what the compiler will optimize away.

Comment: Thanks, the second option looked weird to me anyways!

Comment: The second one is impossible if `Entity` is not copyable/moveable (although this may have changed in C++17; I don't know, I haven't kept up)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it has, the elision is mandated and both forms are strictly equivalent. I remember that there's an examples which goes to great lengths to confirm that `T t = T(T(T(T(a))));` is equivalent to `T t(a);`.

Comment: @Quentin: Then, at the very least, right up until extremely recently (and, on the overwhelming majority of systems, even now) they were not the same.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit indeed. This is one of the changes in C++ that make me wish language versions were better handled on SO.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference for modern compilers because they will optimize

`Entity ent1 = Entity("yourname");`

anyway. But old ones create an temp object then assign in to ent1 using copy constructor.

Comment: Even in new ones (_possibly_ not since C++17 though) the type is at least required to by _copyable_, which is quite a big semantic difference.

Answer (score 0):

`Entity ent("myname");` is called *direct initialization*
`Entity ent1 = Entity("yourname");` is called *copy-initialization*

Since the initializer (`Entity("yourname")`) in the copy-initialization is an [explicit type conversion](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.type.conv), the expression is a *pr-value* whose resulting object is the declared object.

So these two forms are equivalent. You can choose any of them, it is a matter of taste. Some coders prefer the following form, which is also equivalent:

```
auto ent1 = Entity("yourname");
```

Notice it is not a question of optimization, the fact these two forms are equivalent is mandatory.

Comment: I assume this is only true in c++17 [(godbolt link)](https://godbolt.org/g/Z5CZAE)

Comment: I still call that optimization even if it is mandatory. You have to think about it and recognize that it is equivalent.

Comment: @Caninonos Truessness!! All compilers optimized away  the copy before C++17, it has been standardized as mandatory later. So in practice it is true since C++11.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow No it is not any more an optimization (elysion). The rules in C++17 have drastically changed. Now a pr_value is considered to be an expression that iniatializes an object. Actualy the [elysion rule that appeared in C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.copy#31.3) has been [removed in C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.copy#31.3)!! Now it is not more an "elysion" there is just never any temporary materialized!!

Comment: _"So these two forms are equivalent."_ _"So in practice it is true since C++11"_ That is not true. copy-initialization requires (required?) that the object was copyable; direct-initialization doesn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am sure you are able to find other conditions, changing the sited example, where this equivalence breaks! Close to the photon sphere can light orbiting around a black hole access information from a parallel universe?

Comment: If there are situations where the equivalence breaks then there is no equivalence.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Equivalence is a matter of space in which it is applied. Here I considered the generated code for this two expression in this specific case. You have choosen the equivalence: (whatever class S) (S a{x} equivalent S a =S{x}).

Comment: @Oliv: I have chosen the equivalence: "is equivalent".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But you see that in my answer when I site peace of code I explicitly use the class `Entity` he defines with a copy constructor and not an abstract concept "any_class". Realy equivalence is a concept much more relative than what you believe, and truessness is just a property of our own thoughts, what you think are my thoughts are your representation of my thoughts. Are you sure this representation is the truth.

Comment: @Oliv: Yes, I am.